# Generate column from one line [bash]

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

have one text line like this:

```
a b c d e f ...
```

And i want this:

```
a b
c d
e f
...
```

I am trying with sed, awk, for loops, but I have not got it...

Can you help me please??

Thanks!!

Comment: See [ask] for why you're getting downvotes and your question will probably end up getting closed.

Comment: [My answer on UL](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/308654/17666) might be of help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

awk can do it for sure. But for the given example and expected result, I would use `xargs`:

```
xargs -n2 -a file
```

test:

```
kent$  cat f
a b c d e f

kent$  xargs -n2 -a f
a b
c d
e f
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming there might be more than one character between the spaces, so

```
$ cat tmp.txt 
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z

$ cat tmp.txt | sed 's/\([^ ]* [^ ]*\) /\1\n/g'
a b
c d
e f
g h
i j
k l
m n
o p
q r
s t
u v
w x
y z
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `rs`:

```
$ echo a b c d e f ... | rs -C\  0 2
a b 
c d 
e f 
...
```

`man rs`:

```
NAME
     rs — reshape a data array

SYNOPSIS
     rs [-C[x]] [rows [cols]]

DESCRIPTION
     ...
     -C[x]   Output columns are delimited by the single character x.  
             A missing x is taken to be ‘^I’.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo {a..f}
a b c d e f

$ echo {a..f} | tr -s '[:blank:]' '\n' | paste -d " " - -
a b
c d
e f
```

Answer (score 0):

Using only `bash`:

```
$ IFS=$' \t' read -ra a <<< "a b c d e f"
$ printf '%s %s\n' "${a[@]}"
a b
c d
e f
```